# Scraping Instagram with API ?__a=1

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram-api

I've been trying scraping Instagram posts for a certain hashtag for the keys: display_url, taken_at_timestamp, text, edge_liked_by. This goes perfect for some hundreds in the start, but then stops fetching 'text' keyword only. Other three fields are successfully fetched though. I am not sure why it's happening.

I am parsing the JSON https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/something/?__a=1.

```
base_url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/salonedelmobile/?__a=1"
url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/salonedelmobile/?__a=1"
while True:
    response = url_req.urlopen(url)
    json_file = json.load(response)
    for i in json_file['graphql']['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_media']['edges']:
        try:
            post_text = i['node']['edge_media_to_caption']['edges'][0]['node']['text']
        except IndexError as e:
            post_text = e
        try:
            display_url = i['node']['display_url']
        except:
            display_url = e
        try:
            like_count = i['node']['edge_liked_by']['count']
        except:
            like_count = e
        try:
            time_stamp = i['node']['taken_at_timestamp']
        except:
            time_stamp = e
        output.append([display_url, like_count, time_stamp, post_text])
        df = pd.DataFrame(output,columns=['URL', 'Like Count', 'Time', 'Text'])
        try:
            df.to_excel('instagram.xlsx')
        except:
            pass
        if json_file['graphql']['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_media']['page_info']['has_next_page'] == True:
            end_cursor = json_file['graphql']['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_media']['page_info']['end_cursor']
            url = base_url + '&max_id=' + end_cursor
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the JSON structure doesn't change for "text" field in further requests?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't. I am sure

Comment: Any other way to load further data?

Comment: Yes, using the private API. Check this out: https://github.com/ping/instagram_private_api

Comment: You should add time.sleep and timeout with your request. Secondly, make sure that json structure can be changed due to multiple pictures and/or video posts.

Comment: I made sure json structure isn't changing in my case. Well, can we use ?__a=1 or is it blocked?